# This version of the C program runs out of memory. Anyone please tell me why its running out of memory

Tags: c

This version of the C program runs out of memory. Anyone please tell me why its running out of memory. I came across this question during my interview.

```
typedef struct pnode
               {
                 void * ptrData;
                 struct pnode *pNext;
               } NODE ;

void AddNode(NODE *ptrParent, int z);
void Cleanup(NODE *pStart);
void freeList(NODE *pHead);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     NODE *pCurrent;
     NODE start;
     int x =22;
     while (1)
      {
          start.pNext=(NODE *)NULL;
          x=15;
          start.ptrData = (void *)&x;
          pCurrent=&start;
          for (x=0; x<2000; x++)
          {    AddNode(pCurrent,x);
                pCurrent=pCurrent->pNext;
          }
          Cleanup(&start);
      };
}

/*Add Node*/
void AddNode(NODE *ptrParent, int z)
{
      NODE *ptrNew;
      int *ptrData = (int *) NULL;

      /*Allocating memory to ptrNew*/
       ptrNew = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
       if ((NODE *) NULL == ptrNew)
       {
             printf("Out of memory! Exiting\n");
             exit (1);
        }
       /*Allocating memory to ptrData. Please let me know why am in getting out of memory error*/
       ptrData= (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
       if ((int *) NULL == ptrData)
       {
             printf("Out of memory! Exiting\n");
             exit (1);
        }

        *ptrData = z;
        ptrNew->ptrData = (void *)ptrData;
        ptrNew->pNext=(NODE *) NULL;
        ptrParent->pNext = ptrNew;
}

void Cleanup(NODE *pStart)
{
    if ((NODE *)NULL != pStart->pNext)
    {
        freeList(pStart->pNext);
    }
    pStart->pNext=(NODE *)NULL;
    *((int *)pStart->ptrData) = 0;
}

void freeList(NODE *pHead)
{    NODE *pNext;
     pNext = pHead->pNext;
     if (NULL != pHead->pNext)
     {
          freeList(pNext);
          free(pNext);
     }
}
```

Comment: my guess : you don't free the last element of the linked list (because pHead->pNext == NULL) so it leaks memory over time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation Georgesl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had bothered to correctly write your question without breaking the syntax highlighting, you'd have gotten an answer much sooner. The problem is that `AddNode()`

```
 ptrData= (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
 if ((int *) NULL == ptrData)
 {
     printf("Out of memory! Exiting\n"); exit (1); }
 }
```

will allocate memory that is not `free()`'d in `freeList()`

To fix, you'd need to change `freeList()` to something like:

```
 void freeList(NODE *pHead)
 {
     NODE *pNext;
     pNext = pHead->pNext;
     if (NULL != pHead->pNext)
         {
         freeList(pNext);
         free(pNext->ptrData);
         free(pNext);
         }
 }
```

Comment: @user3395194: You might consider accepting my answer, and possibly upvoting it, if it was helpful...

Comment: I am sorry. This is the first time i posted the question. I voted it. Once again Thanks.